# Download button works when logged in but not logged out

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

**Joomla version = 2.5.6**

**PHP version = 5.3**

We are using the [DButton](http://www.etepoc.com) module as a download button inside an article and using 
`{loadposition xxx}` to display it.

About 5 days ago, the button worked fine but since then, something has happened and now it only works if a user is logged in. If they aren't, the button just refreshes the page.  (but does show).

Also during testing we unpublished the module - and it took over 5-10 minutes for the module to 'vanish' when not logged in. When logged in it 'vanishes' immediately and indeed when logging back out it reappeared despite being unpublished!

None of the module files have been edited, nor have we changed anything/installed any new extensions on the website in the last 2 weeks or so.

We used JDump and found no errors within the module, therefore am truly unsure what the problem could be.

We also got in contact with the developers and they said they had never come across or heard of a problem like this before and that they would take a look, however we have not heard from them since.

Reinstalling the module didn't help either.

Has anyone ever come across anything like this before or have an idea or solution?

Comment: What was the answer from the developer when you asked them?

Comment: @Paul: they said they had never come across a problem like this before and would take a look I but haven't heard back fro them since

Comment: Just to add here. What @Lodder says isn't quite strictly true here. JDump will not actually dump any variables when not logged in. Which would suggest there is a severe problem with the module's php not loading correctly. However despite this the button still shows - which is partly why were so confused. I should add it Dumps perfectly correctly as soon as you log in - no changes made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: I never used DButton but looks quite handy.

Are you using custom levels?  What are they set to?   It sounds like something to do with permissions set to registered only instead of public somewhere.

Try disabling all other extensions just in case.

Are you linking to a URL or a file on your server?

Maybe take a backup with Akeeba and install a local version to see if it does the same thing. Can then try replacing your template with a core one as well as uninstalling everything except for DButton.

Comment: If by levels you mean user groups, then no, I'm am not using custom ones, just the standard Joomla ones. The download button module is also set to public and it is linking to a file on the server. I tried disabling some of the extensions I thought might be interfering but still no hope. I will also try testing on wamp but doubt very much this will make a difference.

Comment: @Gisto Also if it were permissions were set to registered for the module then I wouldn't expect the module to show at all. Rather than for the button to show but not to work (The module itself has no checks on user levels - I worked through it all).

Comment: I'd agree - though I was working on a component that did something similar.  In my case it was some sloppy code that tripped me up, otherwise throwing a bunch of ideas out.  The template trick has helped me figure out a few weird behaviors, or at least isolate where the problem is.